# Set data in array of array using mongoose

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got such `User` object:

```
{
    "_id": "584d91ff6c751769fab91be5",
    "username": "svit",
    "name": "Ilya",
    "role": "user",
    "authData": [
        {
            "fb": {
                "access_token": "susdfg",
                "expiration_date": 1,
                "id": "1187410264678321"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 9,
    "currentToken": "9735f44f1c4371f143747ff670b0076148053f391ab866bafab7c6eaf47d295b"
}
```

I am interested in updating `User.authData.fb`. I tried that:

```
var curUser = userModel.findOne({_id: user._id}, function(err, curUser){

        curUser['authData'][socialType] = {
            access_token: socialToken,
            expiration_date:  173249700 //TODO: normal date 
        };

        curUser.set('currentToken', tokenName);

        curUser.markModified('authData');
        curUser.save();
    });
```

But that does just nothing. It modifies `currentToken`, but not `authData`.

Also, I tried `curUser.set('authData.fb.expiration_date", 173249700)`
That does not works too.

I really need your help!
Best regards, 
Ilya

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the 'authData' array and modify whatever values you may like. I am assuming  authData is a array of socialTypes and it has an attribute name to indentify.
example:

```
var curUser = userModel.findOne({_id: user._id}, function(err, curUser){
        curUser.authData.map(socialType => {
        // Select the type of socialAuth you want to modify
         if(socialType.name === 'fb') {
            access_token: socialToken,
            expiration_date:  173249700 //TODO: normal date 
          } 
        })

        curUser.set('currentToken', tokenName);

        curUser.markModified('authData');
        curUser.save();
    });
```